# not able to execute script for limited time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload, upload

I have the following script which displays a loader when a file is uploaded using upload input. I want that loader should appear till the time file uploads and also wish to capture the name of the file. Can anyone please tell how this can be done

```
<input type="file" id="photoimg" name="file"  />
<div id='preview' align="center"></div>


<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#photoimg').change(function(){
$("#preview").html('');
$("#preview").html('<img src=img/loader.gif" alt="Uploading...."/>');
$("#imageform").ajaxForm({
target: '#preview'

});

});
});
</script>
```

Comment: I think you just need `$("#imageform").ajaxForm(function() { $("#preview").empty(); });` and remove the `{ target: '#preview' }`

Comment: @Archer it is not working, the loader still keeps on displaying

Answer (score -1):

You can use ajax call for this once you click the upload button you can show loader image and on the success, you can hide it and if the upload fails you can show the separate image for that.

```
    $.ajax({
      url: 'YOUR API PATH',
      "Show the loader once the ajax call made using .show() or similar"
      error: function() {
        "show the error image using .show() or similar"
      },
      success: function(data) {
         "Hide the loader on success"
      },
      type: 'POST'
    });
```

Comment: can you please show how to do so, because all the ajax code that i came across were using the server link and i don't want that part